# Backbone.js Visual Studio set up

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, backbone.js

Im trying to set up Backbone.js within Visual Studio the guide from the link down below is telling me that I need to install BackBoneSpa.vsix but since its a Visual Studio file extension I need to install ASP.net Web Tools 2012. Is this the only way of adding backbone.js to your visualstudio C# project?

http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/templates/backbonejs-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using backbone.js in empty web app with wep-api in visual studio

Try following this tutorial to provide an api to your backbone models and collections. Visual studio scaffolds the api for you.
[Scaffolding web-api with visual studio](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api).